# How do I make these Outlook 2011 error messages stop?

Tags: ms-office, calendar

Outlook 2011 on OSX has gone bonkers, and I can't make it stop. I've read dozens of web pages, but nobody seems to have an answer. I hope someone here does.

Last week, in preparation for my vacation, I declined *occurrences* of several recurring meetings to tell the organizers I would be away on vacation. This worked except for two of these meetings. Now, as my punishment, my system is slowed by a pair of error messages that prints every few seconds.

[image: Errors]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? For the "Weekly demo" one, I could ask the organizer to cancel and re-send. But for the unnamed one, I have no idea what this could be because all of the recurring meetings on my calendar are named!

In case anyone asks me why I'm still on Outlook 2011, the main reason is that if I upgrade, I will lose the ability to reply below quoted text. (Have you ever seen the stupid, unreadable things people have to do in other versions of Outlook to simulate this using colors and their initials?!)

Comment: Are you using Outlook as a Stand-Alone E-Mail-Client or is it part of an Outlook/Exchange-Architecture?

Comment: What are the full error messages? The log entries **"could not be saved because you do not have the ..."** and **"... could not be saved because..."** give no information at all.

Comment: @J.C.: I am using it with a modern OWA provided by Securence.

Comment: @IconDaemon: None of these messages have any more detail than what's showing. That's the frustrating part. The only difference between the two repeating messages is that one is error -19955 and the other is -19999. Do you know how to turn on more logging? If I click the gear in the upper-right, I can select "Turn on logging for troubleshooting", but I don't know where to look for the logging.